# How to select particular columns with ORDER BY clause in zend framework2

Tags: zend-framework2, tablegateway

I'm new to zend framework and i know this is a beginner level question.But i'm totally messed up.

I want to retrieve only `user_id` and `user_name` form database with descending order of `user_id`.

I'm using tablegateway.

I'm calling getUsersTable() function as

```
$result = $this->getUsersTable()->select();
```

and getUsersTable() function is

```
 public function getUsersTable()
    {
     if(!$this->usersTable)
     {

      $this->usersTable = new TableGateway('eo_user',$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')
      );
     }   
     return $this->usersTable;

    }
```

I searched for similar problem but solution was not looking related to tablegateway.

What changes should i do?Please help.

Comment: Do you have this `getUsersTable()` function written in your Controller? If yes, then its not the way it should be. I hope you have gone through the Album tutorial from http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/modules.html

Answer (score 1):

Just so if `getUsersTable()` function is written in your Controller in the way it is mentioned in the question, you could try this -

1. add this use statement at the top of the Controller -

   use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
2. write this in your action -

   `$select = new Select('eo_user');
    $select->columns(array('user_id', 'user_name'));
    $select->order('user_id DESC');`

   `$result = $this->getUsersTable()->selectWith($select);`

**Note:** If your `getUsersTable()` is actually returning the TableGateway object then the above code will work fine.

If you have created Model-Table class file like in the 'Album' tutorial then just change the line

```
$result = $this->getUsersTable()->selectWith($select);
```

to

```
$result = $this->tablegateway->selectWith($select);
//This is to be written in that Table Class file.
```

I hope it helps someone.